# How to create a harness helm pipeline?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cicd

I am a Harness noob and would like to add a pipeline that applies a helm chart. I would like to do this using a yaml definitions instead of clicking something in the UI, just so that I can check this into version control.

Where can I find a pipeline definition that applies a helm chart?

Comment: related?: https://developer.harness.io/docs/continuous-delivery/deploy-srv-diff-platforms/helm/deploy-helm-charts/